# Set Variable equal to multiple selected cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to get my code to work when multiple cells are selected/changed. I'm not too sure where to go from here as I'm having trouble setting a variable to a target when the target is a multi-cell selection.

An example of what I need would be: All cells in column 1 are selected and deleted, so subsequently I want all cells in column 2 to also be deleted. Instead the code returns an error and does not delete column 2 for any of the selected rows.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim OldValue As String
    Dim NewValue As String

    NewValue = Target.Value

    Application.Undo
    OldValue = Target.Value

    Target.Value = NewValue

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    If OldValue = "" Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        MsgBox "Contents related to this drop-down have been cleared"
    End If
End If

Exithandling:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: How does your code return an error when you have turned off proper error handling? Your code also assumes you are only working with 1 cell being changed. At this point it is still a bit unclear to work out what your code should actually be doing - please explain more detail around the scenario. Remember we can't see your workbook :)

Comment: I have it that way so I can trouble shoot the code as I write it sorry haha. Yes that is my problem. I am telling it to only work with 1 cell (target), but I need it to work with multiple cells. I will see if I can add a screenshot of the workbook

Comment: 1. Do you mean  deleted or **cleared** ? Cleared means the contents are removed; **All cells in column 1 are selected and deleted** means column A is deleted, column B becomes column A and therein lies another problem. Which is it?

Comment: 2. **when multiple cells are selected/changed** do you want changed, selected or both? Content change and cell selection are two very different things.

Comment: 3. If the answer to #1 is cleared, not deleted then what do you plan on doing if a column is actually deleted?

Comment: @jeeped Sorry for not being clear - When it is changed. That could be clearing contents or adding contents. I do not wish to push constraints around the deletion of the column or single cell. Thank you for making me aware of this loophole though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rng As Range, oldVal, newVal, i As Long, num As Long, c As Range

    On Error GoTo haveError:

    'only process the part of Target which overlaps with ColA... 
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(1))

    'run some checks before proceeding...
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rng.Cells.Count = Me.Columns(1).Cells.Count Then Exit Sub 'ignore full-column operations
    If rng.Areas.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub             'handling multiple areas will be more complex...
    If Application.CountBlank(rng) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'no empty cells: nothing to do here

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    newVal = GetArray(rng)
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = GetArray(rng)
    rng.Value = newVal

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        i = i + 1
        If newVal(i, 1) = "" And oldVal(i, 1) <> "" Then
            c.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
            num = num + 1
        End If
    Next c

    If num > 0 Then MsgBox "Contents related to drop-down(s) have been cleared"

haveError:
    If Err <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

'normalizes the array vs. scalar returned when calling .Value
'  on a multi- vs. single-cell range
Function GetArray(rng As Range)
    Dim arr
    If rng.Count > 1 Then
        arr = rng.Value
    Else
        ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        arr(1, 1) = rng.Value
    End If
    GetArray = arr
End Function
```